# Understanding of this if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50

I created a finished code for a mario problem set.

Want to know if I understand the last `if` statement correctly.

If the user enters 4, the code will print out 4 columns with hashes, because it uses the remaining rows to print a blank space on each column.

Just wanted to know, if my point of view is correct.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

  int r, c, ans;

  printf("Value between 0 and 9\n");
  scanf("%d", &ans);

  while (ans < 1 || ans > 8) {
    printf("INVALID REPSONSE PLEASE TRY AGAIN\n");
    scanf("%d", &ans);
  }

  if (ans > 0 || ans <= 8) {
    for (r = 0; r <= ans; r++) {
      for (c = 0; c < ans; c++) {
        if (c >= ans - r) {
          printf("#");
        } else {
          printf(" ");
        }
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The if statement needs to use && instead of ||

Comment: Fuentesj is correct about the if statement.  If you question is about the last if statement, which is if(c >= ans -r), then you are correct with your thinking.  As r grows you will print more and more #'s.  This ends up making a scaling Mario box ramp.

Comment: @fuentesj it looks like `if (ans > 0 || ans <= 8)` is redundant given the `while` loop before it.

Comment: Thanks  everyone for the replies I changed the code and will continue learn more. all your comments are greatly appreciated.